# How do I set up SSH data (or all data) to flow through the VPN PPP adapter?

Tags: windows, ssh, vpn

I am connected to a VPN (L2TP PPP adapter) and would like to use SSH to connect to my server. The server is only allowed to connect from the network I am connected to with the VPN. However, if I try to connect using SSH in the CLI, it won't let me. I can see from the log that it is connecting from my home network, not via VPN.

How do I get SSH to connect through the VPN? Alternatively, how do I set all traffic to flow through the VPN?

In the "network connections" in the "control panel" I have my VPN set as the "default connection". I tried to set a default gateway as well, but it's not available in the GUI and listing all VPNs using PowerShell `Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection` is completely blank.

I am on Windows 10.

---

I would like to use `ssh -i somekey whatever@somewhere` command or atleast something like WinScp.